# How to catch exceptions from another program (for logging)?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, exception

I am working on a tool that monitors a number of applications and ensures they are always running and in a clean state.  Some of these applications have unhandled exceptions which do occur periodically and present the 'send crash report' window.  I do not have the source code to these applications.

Is there any mechanism I could use to catch the exceptions, or simply identify their exception type, as well as identify the application's main executable file that threw the exception.

I'm **not** trying to do anything crazy like catch and **handle it** on the applications behalf, I'm simply trying to capture the exception type, log it and then restart the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trapping unhandled exceptions requires calling SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() in the process.  That's going to be difficult to do if you don't have source code, although it is technically possible by [injecting a DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx) into the process.  This however cannot be done with managed code, you can't get the CLR initialized properly.

The default unhandled exception handler that Windows installs will always run WerFault.exe, the Windows Error Reporting tool.  That can be turned off but that's a system setting.  Expecting your user or admin to do this is not realistic.  Only after WER runs will the JIT debugger get a shot at it.

I recommend a simpler approach, one that's also much more selective.  Use the Process class to get the program you're interested in protecting started.  When the Exited event fires, use the ExitCode property to find out how it terminated.  Any negative value is a sure sign that the process died on an unhandled exception, the exit code matches the exception code.  You can use the EventLog class to read the event message that WER writes to the Windows event log.  And you can restart it the same way you got it started.

Comment: I think the exit code + scanning the event log seems to be the most reliable method.  I just have to make sure the exit event fires before the crash report message comes up... or else its going to require that I scan for any error report boxes (frequently) and auto close them before the exit handling code can run.

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying the source of the application or injecting a DLL into the process I do not believe this is possible in a reliable fashion.  What you're attempting to do is inspect type information across a process boundary.  This is not easy to achieve for a number of reasons

- Getting the name of the exception implies executing code in the target process.  The name can be generated a number of ways (.ToString, or .GetType().Name) but all involve executing some method
- You want to do this after the application has already crashed and hence may be in a very bad state.  Consider trying to execute code if memory was corrupted (perhaps even corrupting the in memory definitions of the type).
- The crash could occur in native code and not involve any managed data

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor application crashes system wide, you can register yourself as a just-in-time debugger.  You can edit the registry to specify which debugger to run when an application crashes.  The example they give is [Doctor Watson](http://www.liutilities.com/products/registrybooster/tweaklibrary/tweaks/10432/), but it could be your application instead.